# Adding Filter to Django REST API

Tags: django, django-views, django-rest-framework

I am pretty new to Django and REST and I want to be able to specify a value and have the REST api only return a row where that value is met. Kinda like in sql `select * from exampleTBL where id = 1` and then the first row is returned. But it would be done through the url: `www.website/api/tmpHost/?id=1` and t hen the first row is returned through the REST API

My view looks like:

```
class tmp_HostList(APIView):
    def get (self, request, format=None):
        tmp_hosts = tmp_Host.objects.all()
        serializer = tmp_HostSerializer(tmp_hosts, many=True, context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = tmp_HostSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

my url looks like:

```
url(r'^api/tmpHost/$', views.tmp_HostList.as_view()),
```

my serializer looks like:

```
class tmp_HostSerializer(DynamicFieldsMixin,  serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = tmp_Host
        fields = '__all__'
```

How would I go about doing this? I've seen solutions around here but they don't seem to work for me. The differences where that I use APIView and my serializer line would be: `serializer = tmp_HostSerializer(tmp_hosts, many=True, context={'request': request})` while theirs would be simple like: `serializer = tmp_HostSerializer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is just check for get parameters and return a filtered object by the parameter:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class tmp_HostList(APIView):

    def get (self, request, format=None):
        param = request.GET.get('id')
        if param:
            tmp_host = get_object_or_404(Host, id=param)
            serializer = tmp_HostSerializer(tmp_host)
        else:
            tmp_hosts = tmp_Host.objects.all()
            serializer = tmp_HostSerializer(tmp_hosts, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

There is also built in filtering for generic views and viewsets [doc link](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/)
But the best choice is create a separate view for detail page or use viewset/generic views.
So your view is stay the same and you add a new one for detail page.
urls:
`url(r'^api/tmpHost/(?P<id>\d+)$', views.tmp_HostList.as_view())`
views:

```
class tmp_HostDetail(APIView):

    def get (self, request, id=None, format=None):
        tmp_host = get_object_or_404(Host, id=id)
        serializer = tmp_HostSerializer(tmp_host)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Where did you get the variable 'q' or is that supposed to be replaced by a filter?

Comment: @JustinBraham it should be `param`. I make a mistake